# Doing psql db dump in Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, dump

I've been trying to dump a db into psql for a few days now and I cannot figure out whats happening here. Latest that I've tried:

```
C:\Users\oefel>psql -U postgres -f trivia.psql trivia_test;
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "trivia_test;" does not exist

C:\Users\oefel>psql -U postgres -f trivia.psql trivia;
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "trivia;" does not exist

C:\Users\oefel>psql -U postgres test_trivia < trivia.psql;
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

These databases definitely exist and I've ensured psql is running. I can see that others have had issues running psql commands in windows and I've tried implementing those solutions but nothing has worked. I'm constantly getting a syntax error near "psql" or whichever word comes first in the command (have tried pg_restore, Get-Content, pg_dump).

Has anyone run into this or could anyone shed some light on the issue? I would really really appreciate it!

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end. That's only required to end SQL statements _inside_ `psql` not to end a command line in Windows

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I'm still getting weird syntax errors with cmd run from the cmd line, but that line worked. Thanks again!